# Find A and B such as f(x)

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to solve this exercize I've found answers but I do not understand the reasoning.

$$\text{Let alpha and beta be two different reals}$$

$$\text{we have}$$ $$f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$x\mapsto \frac{1}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}$$

1)Find A and B such as :

$$\forall x \in I   f(x)=\frac{A}{(x-\alpha)}+\frac{B}{(x-\beta)}$$

I put the frac on the same denominator I get $$\frac{A(x-\beta)+B(x-\alpha)}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}=\frac{1}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}$$

However according to my mathbook we find $A=-B=\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}$ How can we find this result ?

Thank you

Comment: if you compare the numerators, you have $A(x-\beta) + B(x-\alpha)=1$. Substitute in values of $x$ and solve for $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! If you equate the numerators, you get:

$A(x- \beta) + B(x - \alpha) = 1$

To solve for $A$ and $B$ the easiest way would be to find convenient values of $x$ to put in to narrow down the possibilities. I recommend $x = \beta$ and $x = \alpha$.

Finding the numerators for these sorts of problems is called "partial fraction decomposition" if you want to Google more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a nice short cut when the factors of the denominator are linear.

$$\frac A{x-\alpha}+\frac B{x-\beta}=\frac1{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}$$

Mulitply both sides by $x-\alpha$.

$$A+{B(x-\alpha)\over x-\beta}=\frac1{x-\beta}$$

Now, plug $\alpha$ in for $x$ to get

$$A=\frac1{\alpha-\beta}$$

You can you use a similar procedure to find $B$.